# Mongoose - Constructor of model - not all paths are instantiated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
var CampaignAdvertSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    banner: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "CampaignBanner" }
});

var CampaignBannerSchema = new Schema({
    image: { type: String }
});

var CampaignBanner = mongoose.model("CampaignBanner", CampaignBannerSchema);
var CampaignAdvert = mongoose.model("CampaignAdvert", CampaignAdvertSchema);
```

When I do this:

```
var add = new CampaignAdvert({ name: 'aaaaa', banner: { image: "aa" } });

console.log(add);
```

this is printed:

```
{ _id: 562cb14452731c0808d5d1b8, name: 'aaaaa' }
```

why .banner is not created? In previous versions of mongoose I am sure that it was created... Now I am using mongoose 4.1.12

Thanks a lot

Comment: you might want to checkout mongoose's populate() method.

Comment: I am not querying the database, I am just creating a new instance

Answer (score 0):

In your campaignAdvert Schema:

```
 banner: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "CampaignBanner" }
```

banner is expecting an ObjectId, but you are giving it the entire object.